# Issue when assigning tag to UITextField in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I do the following:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UITextField *texfield = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

if (indexPath.section < [self.SmsDataArray count]) {
    SmsModel * smsObj = self.SmsDataArray[indexPath.section];
    texfield.text  = smsObj.phoneNumber;
}
texfield.tag = 10000;
return cell;
```

I am not able to populate the textfield if I change the tag.

If i comment out `texfield.tag = 10000;` the textfield gets populated as expected, what do I need to fix here?

Basically I need to assign the tags to the textfield because the cells are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using the standard cell, then you should subclass `UITableViewCell`, and a create a property to point to your text field so you don't need to use `–viewWithTag:` to get a pointer to it. Then, in `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can assign a `tag` based on the `indexPath.row`.

Comment: So you are saying I should Create a custom class for this cell, ok let me try that

Comment: @AlPacino, yes, you should create a subclass any time you're not using one of the default cell types. In a lot of cases, you only need IBOutlets in the .h file, and nothing in the .m

Answer (score 0):

Problem -- You are overwriting the textfield tag. With the first call tag is changed to 10000.

But this method gets called for the same cell again, it searches textfield having tag 1. But there is no such textfield.

Solution -- Use any substitute of this line

```
(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

for this

1. you can use custom cell and access textfield as "cell.textfield"
2. Or make custom textfield in cellForRowAtIndex(). And set its tag to indexpath.row